# Docker Getting Started Guide Error on Build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am attempting to learn this product in order to containerize my DS experiments. [Part 2: Containerize an Application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) of the Docker Get Started Guide, step 3 demonstrates how to build the image. Executing:

```
$ docker login https://registry-1.docker.io
Username: xxxxxxxx
Password:
Login Succeeded
$ docker build -t getting-started .
```

Returns a 403 Forbidden during the process:

```
[+] Building 59.6s (9/12)                                                   docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 181B                                                        0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                  2.3s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                            0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:ac85f380a63b13dfcefa8904642  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                           0.9s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:0085670310d2879621f96a4216c8  56.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:0085670310d2879621f96a4216c893f92e2  0.0s
 => => sha256:aacbcec05180c1dd8c33dba8a9c42b75dbfdd659aa57617497f1ce2c5d83 1.16kB / 1.16kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:c8eb770fbfacf54104162cc9035c478ddb7d8dc15dca5298af028257f1db 7.14kB / 7.14kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:4abcf20661432fb2d719aaf90656f55c287f8ca915dc1c92ec14ff61e67f 3.41MB / 3.41MB  1.7s
 => => sha256:eb6c7c29ba4d368f2428cacd291f7821b750fac3b1fb65b937ef855c5 40.24MB / 40.24MB  41.9s
 => => sha256:3d4a65156edf0208c8421995310d9e662e7ee63e2bcae660efb02f6c4dde 2.34MB / 2.34MB  1.9s
 => => sha256:0085670310d2879621f96a4216c893f92e2ded827e9e6ef8437672e1bd72 1.43kB / 1.43kB  0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:4abcf20661432fb2d719aaf90656f55c287f8ca915dc1c92ec14ff61e67fbaf8   0.2s
 => => sha256:5bdb6c27eb32087b71a9dde411c1f1eeb87563c0445f89db4eb7639d2cf50f45 0B / 450B   56.1s
 => => extracting sha256:eb6c7c29ba4d368f2428cacd291f7821b750fac3b1fb65b937ef855c573cdf97   2.4s
 => => extracting sha256:3d4a65156edf0208c8421995310d9e662e7ee63e2bcae660efb02f6c4ddef6a9   0.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 5.27kB                                                         0.0s
------
 > [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:0085670310d2879621f96a4216c893f92e2ded827e9e6ef8437672e1bd72f437:
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
   2 |     
   3 | >>> FROM node:18-alpine
   4 |     WORKDIR /app
   5 |     COPY . .
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/node/blobs/sha256:5bdb6c27eb32087b71a9dde411c1f1eeb87563c0445f89db4eb7639d2cf50f45: 403 Forbidden

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/cfrlcah76k0mkdca37uxptuce
```

In researching this I have attempted node:alpine and node:latest with identical results. My environment is MacOS Monterey, corporate network. Appreciate any help here, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are blocked by a firewall. This image is in public access from docker-hub

Answer (score 0):

Access to [https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/node/blobs/sha256:5bdb6c27eb32087b71a9dde411c1f1eeb87563c0445f89db4eb7639d2cf50f45](https://Access%20to%20https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/node/blobs/sha256:5bdb6c27eb32087b71a9dde411c1f1eeb87563c0445f89db4eb7639d2cf50f45%20need%20authorization,%20this%20image%20repository%20need) need authorization

This image repository need authentification.
You need to [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) in your terminal.

```
docker login https://registry-1.docker.io
```

Comment: Same error. Note i have updated my original post to reflect your suggestion. Thank you!